# Can Thymeleaf read variables from a separate file?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

The initial situation is a Thymeleaf base template that provides variables using `th:with`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:with="
            textMainDark='#35393d',
            linkMainDark='#0054a8',
            linkMainLight='#57a5f2'"
      th:fragment="base-layout(content)">

<head>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>

<body>
    <!-- ... -->

    <th:block th:replace="${content}" />

    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

The reason for this approach is, that HTML email templates must declare the style attributes inline, meaning that CSS sections or even style sheets are not possible. This way I can set the attribtes via Thymeleaf variables and can change the look and feel at a single place.

My question is: is it possible to outsource the `th:with` CSS part into its own file and provide these values somehow to the template?

I know that there is always the possibility to introduce another wrapper layer fragment, which only contains the variables and nothing else. But I would be interested in a better solution than the decorate pattern one.